# Actuators used with 2d laser scanners to produce 3D images on ROS

Tags: ros, actuator, laser, ros-kinetic, dynamixel-motor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
The acquisition of 3D LIDAR is mainly based on the rotation of the 2D laser scanner around a certain axis. I mean a standard 2D laser scanner and mechanical rotational element are required for 3D scanning on ROS.  What are the advantages and disadvantages of the actuators used for this( step, servo and dc motor with encoder)? That's why, which motor should ı use? Why? which motor shouldn't ı use? why? Thanks in advance for your helping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291624/actuators-used-with-2d-laser-scanners-to-produce-3d-images-on-ros/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built several 3D LiDAR scanners for our lab using the technique you describe. There are a few factors to consider when choosing an actuator:

1. It needs to be able to accurately
   report its position in space and
   time. You'll need to precisely
   register each 2D LiDAR scan with the
   position of the actuator when that
   scan was captured, so this position
   feedback is very important however
   it is achieved.
2. You'll also want something which
   already has good ROS support; nobody
   want to re-invent the wheel.
3. The actuator also needs to be strong
   and precise enough to repeatedly
   follow exactly the same path, so
   that your 3D scans are consistent.

These requirements can be achieved just as well by a stepper motor system or a DC motor with an encoder, but I would recommend avoiding building something from parts if you can.

We use the [FLIR ptu-46](http://www.flir.co.uk/mcs/view/?id=63554) for our 3D LiDAR scanners, there is a [ROS driver](http://wiki.ros.org/flir_ptu_driver) avilable for this too. It's not the cheapest I have to say but it's strong, reliable and has very good position feedback.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-05-18**:
Thank you for your answer. However, for example, the resolution of the LİDAR we use is 0.352 degree. The resolution of the actuator we use is 0.2.  So much higher. What happens when a situation like this happens?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-18**:
Those two resolutions describe very different concepts, I would say the difference is not that important. The lidar resolution is the angular distance between samples, and the actuator resolution is the precision it can move itself too.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-18**:
At the end of the day you probably want the same angular distance between 2D line scans as there is between individual LiDAR samples within each line. It sounds like you can achieve this fine with the 0.2 degree resolution actuator, so this should be fine.